# Given that $z= \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$, prove that $\Re\left\{\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}\right\}=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Given that $z= \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$, prove that $\Re\left\{\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}\right\}=0$

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{z-1}{z+1}=\frac{z-1}{z+1}\frac{\overline z+1}{\overline z+1}=\frac{|z|^2-1+2i\,\text{Im}\,z}{|z+1|^2}\implies\text{Re}\,\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)=\frac{|z|^2-1}{|z+1|^2}$$

But we know that $\;z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\implies |z|=1\;$ , so...

Comment: What  is that line above z in the second expression, I have never seen that before except for on recurring decimals?

Comment: Er...the complex conjugate of the complex number $\;z\;$ . You *must* have studied this, imo, if you're attempting to do this exercise as it is one of the most basic and elementary definitions in the subject of complex numbers!

Comment: oh ok, yes i know what the conjugate is. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In the denominator of last expression do you mean |z+1| squared instead of |z-1| squared?

Comment: Yes, a typo. Thanks, editing on its way.

Answer (score 2):

If $w=a+ib,\bar w=a-ib\implies w+\bar w=2a$

So, $w$ will be purely imaginary iff $ w+\bar w=0$

Here $$\frac{z-1}{z+1}+\overline{\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{z-1}{z+1}+\frac{\bar z-1}{\bar z+1}=\frac{z\bar z-\bar z+z-1+(z\bar z+\bar z-z-1)}{(z+1)(\bar z+1)}$$

$$=\frac{2(z\bar z-1)}{z\bar z+(z+\bar z)+1}$$

Now, $z\bar z=|z|^2=|\cos\theta+i\sin\theta|^2=1$

Comment: @AnkurSharma, how about this one?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{z-1}{z+1} &= \frac{\cos\theta + i\sin\theta-1}{\cos\theta + i\sin\theta+1} \\
 &= \frac{\cos\theta-1+i\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+1+i\sin\theta} \\
&=\frac{-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} + i\sin\theta}{2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\theta} \\
&= \frac{2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}\cdot\frac{-\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+i\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}} \\
&=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot i\cdot \frac{i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}\\
&= i\tan\frac{\theta}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation} \\
$$
Clearly the above expression is purely imaginary.

Comment: I like this answer the best by the way, for it is the simplest and looks the cleanest :)

Answer (score 1):

Using $\displaystyle\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A $ and $\displaystyle\sin2A=2\cos A\sin A,$

$$\frac{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta-1}{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta+1}=\frac{-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}2+i2\sin\frac{\theta}2\cos\frac{\theta}2}{2\cos^2\frac{\theta}2+i2\sin\frac{\theta}2\cos\frac{\theta}2}$$

$$=\frac{2i\sin\frac{\theta}2\left(\cos\frac{\theta}2+i\sin\frac{\theta}2\right)}{2\cos\frac{\theta}2\left(\cos\frac{\theta}2+i\sin\frac{\theta}2\right)}=i\tan\frac{\theta}2$$  as $\displaystyle\cos\frac{\theta}2+i\sin\frac{\theta}2\ne0$